# Google Maps API vs Google Maps Engine?

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm brand new to web technologies, and in researching a web app that I want to create I got a little bogged down.  I want to be able to use a Google Map on my site, including the functionality that allows you to use layers and draw shapes and lines on top of it, but I'm confused at the difference between the Google Maps API and Google Maps Engine and which one would best suit me.

Is one of those a better option for me?  There seems to be a lot of red tape on getting Maps Engine for a site, but I'm unclear on if Maps API has all the functionality I'd want.

Sorry for the beginner question, but I haven't found any sort of FAQ that's addressed this.  I'd really appreciate any insight.  Thanks!

Comment: I know you can do styled maps with Maps API, not sure if that's what you want: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Comment: Ah, elsewhere in that documentation there's a "Drawing on the Map" section, which is what I was looking for.

Comment: In all probability, you want the Google Maps Javascript API V3. The need to move up to the Engine is rare.

Comment: Okay, so am I to understand that Maps Engine is meant to build one's "own" map application (using the API), while the standalone API can only be used to access a map directly from Google?  Sorry, the presentation on Google's documentation is a bit confusing still

Comment: Yes, as I understand it. The Google Maps Engine is categorized by Google under "Maps for Business" meaning it's  gonna cost you $$$. Even if you have $$$ to burn then start with the Google Maps Javascript API V3 and discover its limitations. You will probably find it does what you want, plus or minus.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense for starting out.  I'm building the site on Google "App" Engine, so when I discovered there was a Google "Maps" Engine as well I got all turned around.  Thanks a bunch for the help!

Answer (score 10):

So Google actually offers three different products.

- [**Google Maps JavaScript API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) is intended for developers, and it lets you take Google's base maps and draw on them programmatically by writing your own JavaScript that calls the API.
- [**Google Maps Engine**](https://www.google.com/enterprise/mapsearth/products/mapsengine.html) is for creating your own base maps.  You could use it to render shapes and lines on top of a map, but if that's all you want to do, it's probably overkill (and it's not free).
- [**Google Maps Engine Lite**](https://support.google.com/mapsengine/answer/3024396?hl=en) is the new boy in town, and it's still beta as I type this, but it might fit your use case the best: you can draw by hand on top of Google's standard maps, import a variety of formats with geo data, and then [share your results or embed them on your website](https://support.google.com/mapsengine/answer/3024935?hl=en&ref_topic=3038155), all without having to write a lick of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how comfortable you are with coding. Google Maps API requires the application to be built in JavaScript.

As Google Maps Engine has now been shelved by Google I would suggest taking a look at [MangoMap](https://mangomap.com). It allows maps to be built using only an interface, you can built really powerful web ma applications without writing a single line of code.

Disclaimer: I'm the CEO of MangoMap ;-)

Comment: Is this interoperable with R programming language? Does it have package for this program?

Answer (score 0):

With Google Maps API, Google supplies a blank map and you add points, line, polygons, etc. to the map via JavaScript. This is great until you start having to add thousands of map objects.

With [Google Maps Engine](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/), ([now deprecated](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/)), you upload, store, and process the geometry data on Google's servers for optimal rendering. You can turn a large group of points and lines into image files with transparent backgrounds which can display quickly on a map.