# Google Maps Engine API (Deprecated)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-engine

I am currently developing a software using google maps API, it states that the google API is going to be disabled on January 29th, 2016, does this mean i am waisting my time?

https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/

Answer (score 1):

It means that your software product will not be usable after that date. Whether or not you are wasting your time is dependent on when and for how long you require your software to be functional. However keep in mind that this is the Google Maps Engine API and not the Google Maps API (as the wording in your question refers to).

Comment: I am using google maps API, not not google maps engine API, when it says "deprecated" does this mean my software wont work anymore?

Comment: Yes because any API calls to the Google Maps Engine API will not be functional. However if you are not using the Google Maps Engine API (and instead using only the Google Maps API) then you will be fine. It is important to recognize that the Google Maps API is not the same thing as the Google Maps Engine API.

Comment: What's the difference between Google Map Engine and Google Map? This explanation is not too thorough, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285659/google-maps-api-vs-google-maps-engine